# Why did my computers suddenly stop talking to my HDMI projector?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, projector

I have an Optoma ML750 projector that I have been using with my custom desktop for the past few weeks. I connect the projector through a KINIVO 3-to-1 HDMI switcher so I can display my gaming console, cable, or PC output on the same projector.

This morning when I left for work my projector was working just fine, but when I got back my monitors had fallen asleep and my desktop no longer recognized my projector as an available monitor. I have tried rebooting my computer and projector in every permutation, eliminated the switcher, tried different cables, and tried hooking up my projector to my laptop which also failed to recognize my projector.

However, when I hook up my cable box or gaming console they both work fine on the projector. For some reason it's only monitor detection that is failing.

I have NVIDIA graphics cards on both my desktop and laptop (GTX 760 and GT525M respectively).

Any troubleshooting ideas? What would cause my projector to suddenly become unrecognizable but still functional with sources that don't require recognition?

Comment: Does the projector still power on, show on-screen display menus, and otherwise appear to function as usual? Does the lamp come on? Do the USB and SD card input functions still work? How about wireless signal input?

Comment: As I said, it works just fine with my TV box and console. Have not tried the USB and SD cards because I don't use those but I am currently using an HDMI to VGA adapter as a workaround.

Comment: I mean does the projector turn on when connected to the PC, but it doesn't sound like that the issue anyway. Did you try reinstalling the gfx card drivers?

Comment: I did reinstall drivers. The projector is definitely detecting hot plug. I'm starting to suspect the projector's DDC capability is shot.

Comment: Is the projector's firmware upgradeable?